# DexGuard error while trying to enable minifying in ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, minify, dexguard

I am trying to enable minifying in an Android app using ProGuard.

When I set `minifyEnabled` to `false` it builds but as soon as I set it to `true`:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        jniDebuggable true
        versionNameSuffix '_DEBUG'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
        proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

I get a gradle syncing error:

```
ERROR: minifyEnabled is set to 'true' for variant <name of the variant>.
```

And stacktrace states:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':MainApp'
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Errors occurred during DexGuard plugin configuration.
```

What does DexGuard have to do here?

Comment: In release mode, you are settings dexguard in some properties

Comment: My bad, I made a confusion between DexGuard and ProGuard in terms of plugin used by my development team.

Answer (score 3):

Dexguard's documentation says:

> DexGuard expects its inputs to be unobfuscated, so make sure none of the variants you specify here have the minifyEnabled options set to true.

You can't use both Dexugard and Proguard in the same library. You have to either disable Dexguard or Proguard.

Dexguard is an improved (and paid) version of Progurad. I don't see any reason for using Proguard when you have Dexguard.